# Which TeX App and packages are optimal for creating slides on Japanese?

Tags: beamer, slideshow

The settings in `beamer` for japanese language providing are too complicated, same as any oter class for slides which is not adapted for japanese. I find some TeX-based class, application, or package for slides creating which comfortable if use japanese.

For now, I use japanese-language classes in `LuaLaTeX` (e. g. `ltjsarticle`) and `XeLaTeX` and appropriate packages (e. g. `luatexja-fontspec`) for normal documents. It will be great if exists similar tools for slides as `beamer` but adapted for japanese.

Comment: The question i asked myself on october 4th: Can't you just load `luatexja-fontspec` (whatever it does)  with `beamer`? Execpt for the template stuff that takes care of layout, there is no difference in functionality with `article`. In which situations does `beamer` fail with the japanese script.